Send the file to the browser when it has downloaded 100%
For example, we have a link to the file like
<a href="/file.zip">file.zip</a>
Let the filesize will be 1000Mb.
If we click on the link, the browser will start downloading immediately, right? Right!
But I would like to do the following:

User clicks on the link
I draw a loading animation from 0 to 100%
And as soon as the file has been completely downloaded and reached 100%, open a browser dialog box to save the finished downloaded file.

How can i do this?
There were no attempts, because... I don't know how to use this.

Why do you want to do this?

My browser already has a download panel that can show me the current download progress. And anything you implement via AJAX instead, is likely to be a much bigger drain on resources, than just letting the browser handle the download natively.

you could check this answer and MDN docs on how to check the progress of a XMLHttpRequest
